# Find out if a combination of 2 Cells values right next to each has been entered previously in 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

So I have column A and B, we manually enter the values of this 2 columns to record when we change from Part A to Part B, if its in the file it means the change could be performed after some investigation. We do this manually every time a change of part number is requested.

To avoid this search with manual search or filtering, I want to know if its possible with an Excel Macro or a function to search in the whole columns if the combination of the values in, for example, A2131 & B2131 have been entered before (For example it was entered before in A1521 & B1521), and if yes, return a 1 or a yes, or anything that tells me it has been done before, and if it isn't, return something else.

I have tried to use vlook up, but I can only compare one column vs another, is there a way to compare 2 columns for example, which is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly how you want these annotated, but you can use COUNTIFS to provide this analysis.  Assuming your data begins in A2 and B2, you would put this formula in C2:

=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)>1,"Duplicates","")

and then copy it down for all rows.  Any row where both columns A and B match another row's column A and B will show the word "Duplicates" in column C of all matching rows.[image]

Comment: Hello, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.